# Python 2 change the way to start a new process

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Can I change the way Python 2 creates a new process, like what `set_start_method` does in Python 3 on UNIX based OSes?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the `multiprocessing` module? Your question doesn't make it clear whether you're open to using other tools to start processes.

Comment: @user2357112 doesn't really matter. as long as it works and it's not too complicated to manage. anything that allow me to _spawn_ new processes with fresh python interpreter process.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `Process` class that mocks original attributes but internally uses `subprocess` for starting another Python interpretator with required arguments: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family

Though I would suggest you taking a look at awesome `gevent` library for much more multiprocessing/multithreading possibilities: http://www.gevent.org/gevent.os.html